# Using django's `reverse_lazy` and concatenizing it

Tags: python, django

I want to insert a resolved URL into a string, used as the `help_text` of a form field:

```
class ContactForm(forms.Form):

    [...]

    email_sender = forms.EmailField(
        label="Votre email",
        widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs={'disabled': 'disabled'}),
        help_text="[...], <a href='{}'>[...]</a>.".format(reverse_lazy('account_email'))
    )
```

But inserting the reversed URL into the string is not possible, because the `format` function (or any concatenation way I tried) is not "lazy", and wants to produce the output immediately.

I get the following error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The included urlconf 'myproject.urls' does not appear to have any patterns in it. If you see valid patterns in the file then the issue is probably caused by a circular import.
```

For example, using the following code works perfectly, but is not what I want :)

```
    email_sender = forms.EmailField(
        help_text=reverse_lazy('account_email')
    )
```

So how do I concatenate a string of "lazy" values?

Comment: Why not just use `reverse` instead of `reverse_lazy`?

Comment: The error would be the same, as the URLs are not yet loaded, and are thus not accessible. To be more precise, the second example would not even work (`help_text=reverse('account_email')`).

Comment: Makes sense... Django has some string utility functions in django.utils.translation that may be useful here. Try checking out ugettext_lazy() and string_concat()

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Note:** This was written in the times of Django 2. While the essence is still valid as of Django 4, the helper function described in this post is now provided out-of-the-box as [`format_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.format_lazy).

---

You cannot concatenate lazy strings in Django. The implementation is very basic, it's not even actual lazy strings, it's lazy function calls, they may return other types. When you do `reverse_lazy`, you do just get a lazy function call with no special other behavior

So, just play by the rules. If you need a string to be lazily computed, create a lazy function yourself:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy

def email_sender_help_text():
    return "[...], <a href='{}'>[...]</a>.".format(reverse('account_email'))

email_sender_help_text_lazy = lazy(email_sender_help_text, str)
```

You can now use it:

```
email_sender = forms.EmailField(
    help_text=email_sender_help_text_lazy()
)
```

Or, for a more general version:

```
from django.utils.functional import lazy

def format(string, *args, **kwargs):
    return string.format(*args, **kwargs)
lazy_format = lazy(format, str)
```

```
help_text=lazy_format("<a href='{}'>", reverse_lazy('account_email'))
```

You may also want to check out [`django.utils.functional.allow_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.allow_lazy).

---

**Later edit:**
Since Django 3, Django provides exactly that helper function, as [`format_lazy`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.format_lazy). So use that instead of recreating it.

Comment: Nice, it solved my problem. Creating a lazy "string" was the answer.

Comment: Thank you, very helpful.

Answer (score 4):

In the latest versions of django, there is a util function called `format_lazy`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/utils/#django.utils.text.format_lazy